# A Pathwise Optimization Problem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose $X$ is a nonnegative semimartingale that is progressively measurable with respect to a given filtration $\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\ge 0}$. Let $c:\mathbb R_+ \mapsto \mathbb R_+$ be a strictly convex function such that $\liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{c(x)}{x} =\infty$. For simplicity, we can further assume that $c$ is continuously differentiable. Let $ T>0$. Can we find a nonnengative and $\mathcal F_t$-adapted process $u$ so that \begin{equation}\label{eq1}X(T)u(t) - c(u(t)), \quad 0\le t < T\end{equation} is maximized for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$? If we replace $X(T)$ in the above equation by $X(t)$, then the solution is given by $u^*(t) = (c')^{-1}(X(t))$.  But I don't know how to handle this problem with an $X(T)$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In case X is a martingale and u  is adapted then $EX(T)u(t) -c(u(t)) = E(X(t)u(t) - c(u(t))$ so you can't uniformly dominate the solution of maximizing $X(t)u(t) - c(u(t))$.  The same would hold for a semimartingale for which there is a martingale measure.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful observation!